# How is the 30sec defined when obtained from Spotify API's track's preview_url?

Tags: python, spotify

I am interested to use an audio raw dataset provided by Spotify Web API in Python. I wonder if the audio sample follows any rules to define the 30sec provided by the [`preview_url`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/tracks/get-track/).

> preview_url | string |    A link to a 30 second preview (MP3 format) of the track. Can be `null`

Is the 30sec of the track extracted from:

1. The first 30 sec?
2. The track after 1 minute?
3. The track between 1-3mins?
4. A random part of the track?

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, you may not be the right person, but I am learning why my question is being closed?

Comment: I edited your post to add a link and a snippet to the `preview_url` API doc of Spotify, to add more details. I also cleaned up the irrelevant tags (please read the tag descriptions). The edits are a bit much, and if you don't like my edits, you can [rollback them](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64925963/revisions) them to your original. What you can do to improve it further is to show some sample attempts at using that API for some sample tracks.

Comment: Thanks Gino, its actually helpful to learn how to convey the message here. Regardless, someone replied my message on the previous version. Once again, really appreciated your help!

Comment: It seems you re-asked the exact same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64979102/2745495, instead of clarifying this original question and waiting for it to get reopened. Please refrain from doing that in the future, that's not how things work here. I'm voting to close this then as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Alrighty, thanks for your sharing. As I would like to hear more other opinions (provided I am lucky), let me close the original post and remain this one then.