# How is a track's 30sec defined that's obtained from preview_url (Spotify Web API)?

Tags: spotify

I am interested to use an audio raw dataset provided by Spotify Web API in Python. I wonder if the audio sample follows any rules to define the 30sec provided by the [`preview_url`](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/tracks/get-track/).

> preview_url | string |    A link to a 30 second preview (MP3 format) of the track. Can be `null`

Is the 30sec of the track extracted from:

1. The first 30 sec?
2. The track after 1 minute?
3. The track between 1-3mins?
4. A random part of the track?

Answer (score 0):

Spotify analyses every track and then is able to tell where different parts of the song begin and end.

I suppose that what you hear in the 30s preview is a guess that Spotify makes of what the refrain/main part of the songs is.

Therefore you can't generally say which part is chosen because that is determined by an AI for each song respectively.